# In the following function why After showing Hello(6,5,....1),then space shows increment in counter?

Tags: java, recursion

In the following function why After showing Hello(6,5,....1),then space shows increment in counter?

```
private void myMethod(int counter)
{
    if (counter == 0)
    {
        System.out.println("");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Hello" + counter);
        myMethod(--counter);
        System.out.println("" + counter);
    }
}
```

Program Output when 6 is passed to method:

```
Hello6
Hello5
Hello4
Hello3
Hello2
Hello1

0
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "then space shows increment in counter"? That's very unclear to me. It would help if you would show a short but complete program, the actual output, and the expected output.

Comment: when counter =5 OUTPUT   Hello5
Hello4
Hello3
Hello2
Hello1

0
1
2
3
4

Comment: No, that really doesn't explain what you mean. You need to put effort into being as clear as you possibly can - see http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Comment: OP isn't really clear but I think he means there is a blank line in his output.

Comment: @JamieReid: I *suspect* so too, but if the OP edited the question it would make it a lot easier to tell.

Comment: If the problem *is* an empty line - what did you expect `System.out.println("")` to do?

Comment: I also wondered that, but at the moment I have edited the question only to show the program output as I literally have no idea what OP is asking us. Just awaiting peer review.

Answer (score 0):

The second print is first called if the recursion is fully done, this means it counts backwards, since the last called method finishes first.

If that's what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

(not actually code but used for a diagram)
When using myMethod(3):

```
mM(3)->|prints: "Hello3"
       |mM(2)-------------->|prints: "Hello2"
       |prints:....         |mM(1)-------------->|prints: "Hello1"
                            |prints....          |mM(0)----------->|prints: ""
                                                 |prints....
```

because each else has three statements, and they do them in order from top to bottom, the first print statement is executed first, and then the recursion happens next, which temporarily skips the the second print until the base statement 0 is reached, and then it goes backwards and does the second print for each else. (if this is what you're asking)